# Not able in accessing textView from linearlayout using findViewById in listview in onItemClick

Tags: android

i am able to display a listview from an array.But when i click on any of the row aplication crashes saying **ClassCaste Exception android.widget.linearlayout**.
my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<ImageView android:id="@+id/icon" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="22px"
    android:layout_marginTop="4px" android:layout_marginRight="4px"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4px">
</ImageView>
<TextView android:text="@+id/TextView01" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/label"
    android:textSize="30px"></TextView>
```

specific code where error could exist:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> countryAdapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.rowlayout,R.id.label,countries);
    setListAdapter(countryAdapter);
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

and onclick method ,where i am trying to show toast on the clickd item from the list view:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView)linearlayout.findViewById(R.id.label)).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

**application is crashing when i am clicking on any of the list item.**

any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: What u did in this Part?  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ((TextView)linearlayout.findViewById(R.id.label)).getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Comment: in the `onItemClick` method, where are you getting the `linearLayout` reference from?

Comment: trying to access child node of linear layout(already declared) and then typecasting it into textview.my dumb mind:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
((TextView)linearlayout.findViewById(R.id.label)).getText()
```

by

```
((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.label)).getText()
```

Hope it works :)